# How to add Constraints between Form fields of HTML forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I was wondering if there is already a framework or a jquery plugin which i can use to add constraints to form fields. With "constraints" in this case I don't want to say that field x is an e-mail field and needs to be validated as such but i want to define relations between form fields like:

- If there is something selected in checkbox A --> **enable Button B**
- If there are at least X entries selected in list A --> **enable form field B**

and so on and so forth..

I'm currently on the point of implementing it myself but I wanted to make sure that I don't reinvent the wheel.

It could be any JavaScript framework (standalone or jquery plugin).

Comment: Have you tried to do a search? Found this on github: https://github.com/keyo/jQuery-Form-Dependency

Comment: Obviously "Dependency" is a much better search term than "Contraint". Would you mind making your comment an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jQuery plugin you could use:
http://github.com/keyo/jQuery-Form-Dependency

Answer (score 3):

Why a plugin? This is fairly easy with just jQuery:

```
$('input.A:checkbox').change(function() {
    $('button.B').prop('disabled', !($(this).prop('checked'));
});
$('select.C').change(function() {
    $('button.D').prop('disabled', !($(this).find('option:selected').length >= 10));
});
```

We're just assigning handlers to the events that happen when the inputs are changed - and I enable or disable the field depending on my condition.

I think it's better than getting a plugin because:

1. You're saving on HTTP requests for more files
2. You're saving performance by not loading more JS code
3. This is fairly simple as-is and there's no point to overcomplicate it.

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vPJ4J/)

Comment: what about some explanation?

Comment: What do you need help with? `prop` changes properties, in this case `disabled`, and it changes to the opposite value of my condition (because it's `disabled` and not `enabled`) so it should be `false` if I have over 10 selected items

Comment: From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), "the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes."

Comment: Thanks, but i need this to me more in a "configurable" manner then in a programming manner because the forms i'm creating are dynamic and generated. I can't program the contraints for each form.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. But I disagree with your reasoning not to use a framework. Most frameworks worth their salt are written to simplify and lessen the amount of code/javascript you have to write to achieve a certain result. You might take on knock in adding an extra library, but with things like bundling caching & compression its not that much... AND if you have a fair amount of validation to do, writing tons of custom logic vs, a flexible extension... a plugin would result in less and cleaner code.

Comment: I see, I suggest just doing this a bit more dynamically (using `.on()` and choosing your selectors wisely) because I don't really see how configurable constraints would save anything, you will most likely need to configure very specific constrains for each generated form, they would most likely not save you a lot of code

Comment: @RohanBüchner I agree that a lot of things are better off with plugins, but the nature of constraints are that even the worst ones aren't too complex, so it's going through a lot of trouble for something not-that-much-more efficient

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like knockout you'd be able to make use of the [knockoutvalidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) framework.. or, in the past I've used [jqbootstrapvalidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/)... the latter obviously requires bootstrap as well.

There are quite a few code samples on both sites & both frameworks are pretty easy to use. Feel free to comment on this post if you need any more specific help/advice.

**Just a word of warning**. If you do use knockout. Go with [knockoutvalidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/), and not bootstrap validation... or you'll have sleepless nights trying to get the 2 to play nicely.